# image is not uploading after crop using retrofit android

Tags: android, image, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

im referring to this tutorial for cropping --> https://www.android-examples.com/android-image-cropping-example-tutorial-pick-gallery-camera/

it is placing the cropped image in imageview in edit profile activity on submitting it is showing success that updated successfully.. but on acccount activity it is not showing image on profilepic...

when debugged it is only showing this--> `data:image/png;base64` but not with encoded string(AVDBJSV3jq..)

why convertostring is null and why is it not appending string after this data:image/png;base64

i dont know why is it null

need help thanks in advance

Following is my code

```
class EditProfile:AppCompatActivity (){
var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
var profile:ImageView?=null
var uri: Uri? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.editprofile)
    var mActionBarToolbar = findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbartable);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
    val myCalendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    val edittext1 = findViewById(R.id.dob) as EditText
    val date =
        OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth -> // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            val myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" //In which you need put here
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
            edittext1.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()))      }

    edittext1.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            DatePickerDialog(
                this@EditProfile, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            ).show()
        }
    })
   val edit= edittext1.text
     profile = findViewById<View>(R.id.profilepic) as ImageView


    val token :String =SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext).user.access_token.toString()
    RetrofitClient.instance.fetchUser(token)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<My_account_base_response> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<My_account_base_response>, t: Throwable) {

                Log.d("res", "" + t)
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<My_account_base_response>,
                response: Response<My_account_base_response>
            ) {
                var res = response

                if (res.body()?.status == 200) {

                    val retro: Myaccount_data = res.body()!!.data
                    val retro1: User_data = retro.user_data
                    Glide.with(applicationContext).load(retro1.profile_pic)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .into(profile!!)
                } else {
                    try {
                        val jObjError =
                            JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        Log.e("errorrr", e.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    profile?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        val GalIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 2)
    })
    editsubmit.setOnClickListener {

        val first_name = firstname.text.toString().trim()
        val last_name = lastname.text.toString().trim()

        val email = emailregister.text.toString().trim()
        val phone = phoneno.text.toString().trim()

        val profile ="data:image/png;base64,"+convertToString()!!
        val token: String =
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(
                applicationContext
            ).user.access_token.toString()
        val first_name1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), first_name)
        val last_name1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), last_name)
        val email1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), email)
        val dob1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), edittext1.text.toString())
        val phone_no1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), phone)
        val profile_pic = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
            profile
        )


        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", profile)
        val map: MutableMap<String, RequestBody> = HashMap()

        map.put("first_name", first_name1);
        map.put("last_name", last_name1);
        map.put("email", email1);
        map.put("dob", dob1);
        map.put("phone_no", phone_no1);
        map.put("profile_pic", profile_pic);
        val requestFile: RequestBody =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), profile)

        val body: MultipartBody.Part =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "image.jpg", requestFile)
        RetrofitClient.instance.useredit(token, map)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("res", "" + t)
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                    response: Response<LoginResponse>
                ) {
                    var res = response
                    Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
                    if (res.body()?.status == 200) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            res.body()?.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        Log.d("kjsfgxhufb", response.body()?.status.toString())
                    } else {
                        try {
                            val jObjError =
                                JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                jObjError.getString("message") + jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                            Log.e("errorrr", e.message)
                        }
                    }

                }
            })
    }
}
private fun convertToString(): String? {
      val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
    bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)

    val imgByte: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imgByte, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP)
}

override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode === 0 && resultCode === RESULT_OK) {
        ImageCropFunction()
    } else if (requestCode === 2) {
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.data
            ImageCropFunction()
        }
    } else if (requestCode === 1) {
        if (data != null) {
            val bundle = data.extras
            val bitmap = bundle!!.getParcelable<Bitmap>("data")
            profile?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }

}
fun ImageCropFunction() {
    try {
       val CropIntent = Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP")
        CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*")
        CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true")
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 180)
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 180)
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 3)
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 4)
        CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true)
        CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true)
        startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    }
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)

            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: No idea, but I'd try sending up image directly via OkHttpClient and not necessarily through Retrofit. that helped me once

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for reverting...but i dont think it is due to network call...because it is line failed to encode the image ==> `val profile ="data:image/png;base64,"+convertToString()!!` after debugg...im able to see only this data:image/png;base64, not with big long string

Comment: In `convertToString()` method, you've used `bitmap`. Where did you initialise this variable?

Comment: here --> var bitmap: Bitmap? = null @shafayathossain

Comment: And where did you put bitmap value?

Comment: here -->   val bitmap = bundle!!.getParcelable<Bitmap>("data")
                profile?.setImageBitmap(bitmap) @shafayathossain

Comment: @shafayathossain why is convertostring is getting null in here --> `val profile ="data:image/png;base64,"+convertToString()!!` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put bitmap into new variable. You've to put that into global variable.

```
bitmap = bundle!!.getParcelable<Bitmap>("data") profile?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Just remove `val` before `bitmap` where you're trying to set new bitmap image into the variable.

Comment: new question --> need help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371863/onresume-does-not-worked-in-viewmodel