# onResume does not worked in viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, lifecycle

my data is fetched only when it is created...im using viewmodel...when press back button it doesnt update the previous data..onresume is not working in this...

i refered this but none of those helped--> [Reacting to activity lifecycle in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566018/reacting-to-activity-lifecycle-in-viewmodel/52634049)

i need help

thanks in advance

activity:--

```
class MyAccount : BaseClassActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.myaccount)



    var mActionBarToolbar = findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbartable);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
  setEnabledTitle()


    val resetbutton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.resetpwd)
    resetbutton.setOnClickListener {
        val i=Intent(applicationContext,
            ResetPasswordActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }
    val editbutton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.editdetail)
    editbutton.setOnClickListener {
        val i=Intent(applicationContext, EditProfile::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }

  hello()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
  hello()

}

fun hello(){
    val first_name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.firstname)
    val last_name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lastname)
    val emailuser = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.emailuser)
    val phone_no = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.phone_no)
    val birthday = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.birthday)
    val image=findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageprofile)


    val model = ViewModelProvider(this)[MyAccountViewModel::class.java]

    model.viewmodel?.observe(this, object : Observer<My_account_base_response> {
        override fun onChanged(t: My_account_base_response?) {
            first_name.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.first_name)
            last_name.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.last_name)
            emailuser.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.email)
            phone_no.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.phone_no).toString()
            birthday.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.dob).toString()
            Glide.with(applicationContext).load(t?.data?.user_data?.profile_pic)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)

                .into(image)
        }
    })


}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)

            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}}
```

viewmodel:--

```
class MyAccountViewModel(context: Application) :AndroidViewModel(context),LifecycleObserver{
private var MyAccountViewModels: MutableLiveData<My_account_base_response>? = null
val viewmodel: MutableLiveData<My_account_base_response>?
    get() {
        if (MyAccountViewModels == null) {
            MyAccountViewModels = MutableLiveData<My_account_base_response>()
            loadviewmodel()
        }
        return MyAccountViewModels

    }

private fun loadviewmodel(){
    val token :String = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplication()).user.access_token.toString()
    RetrofitClient.instance.fetchUser(token)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<My_account_base_response> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<My_account_base_response>, t: Throwable) {

                Log.d("res", "" + t)


            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<My_account_base_response>,
                response: Response<My_account_base_response>
            ) {
                var res = response

                if (res.body()?.status == 200) {
                    MyAccountViewModels!!.value = response.body()

                } else {
                    try {
                        val jObjError =
                            JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                            jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e("errorrr", e.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}}
```

Comment: `if (MyAccountViewModels == null) ` and then you `MyAccountViewModels = MutableLiveData<My_account_base_response>()` that means when on resume happens that will not be null and youst returns the else `MyAccountViewModels`

Comment: im returning return `MyAccountViewModels` @cutiko

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are bunch of things wrong here, so let me provide you refactored code and explanation as much as I would be able to..

Activity:

```
class MyAccount : BaseClassActivity() {
    private val mActionBarToolbar by lazy { findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbartable) }
    private val resetbutton by lazy { findViewById<Button>(R.id.resetpwd) }
    private val editbutton by lazy { findViewById<Button>(R.id.editdetail) }
    private val first_name by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.firstname) }
    private val last_name by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lastname) }
    private val emailuser by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.emailuser) }
    private val phone_no by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.phone_no) }
    private val birthday by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.birthday) }
    private val image by lazy { findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageprofile) }
    lateinit var model: MyAccountViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.myaccount)
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar)
        setEnabledTitle()
        model = ViewModelProvider(this)[MyAccountViewModel::class.java]
        resetbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(applicationContext, ResetPasswordActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
        editbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(applicationContext, EditProfile::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
        model.accountResponseData.observe(this, object : Observer<My_account_base_response> {
            override fun onChanged(t: My_account_base_response?) {
                first_name.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.first_name)
                last_name.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.last_name)
                emailuser.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.email)
                phone_no.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.phone_no).toString()
                birthday.setText(t?.data?.user_data?.dob).toString()
                Glide.with(applicationContext)
                    .load(t?.data?.user_data?.profile_pic)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .into(image)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        model.loadAccountData()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)

                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Few notes on your activity class:

1. You don't need to `findViewById` everytime, just do it once during `onCreate` or do it lazily. *(FYI consider using kotlin synthetics or view binding or data binding)*
2. Initialize your `viewModel` during `onCreate` method only. *(That's the best way to do it)*
3. Also observer your `LiveData` from `ViewModel` once, it should be also from the `onCreate` as it's the entry point to the activity and apart from config changes this method called only once. So, it's safe to observe it over there rather than during `onResume` which will be called multiple times during activity lifecycle. *(The main issue your code wasn't working, so as a fix you only call your API method from `ViewModel` during resume)*

ViewModel:

```
class MyAccountViewModel(context: Application) : AndroidViewModel(context) {
    private val _accountResponseData = MutableLiveData<My_account_base_response?>()
    val accountResponseData: MutableLiveData<My_account_base_response?>
        get() = _accountResponseData

    init {
        loadAccountData()
    }

    fun loadAccountData() {
        val token: String = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplication()).user.access_token.toString()
        RetrofitClient.instance.fetchUser(token)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<My_account_base_response> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<My_account_base_response>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("res", "" + t)
                    _accountResponseData.value = null
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<My_account_base_response>,
                    response: Response<My_account_base_response>
                ) {
                    var res = response

                    if (res.body()?.status == 200) {
                        _accountResponseData.value = response.body()
                    } else {
                        try {
                            val jObjError =
                            JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                            Toast.makeText(
                                getApplication(),
                                jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.e("errorrr", e.message)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

1. Don't make initial API call along with `LiveData` creation, it's okay to do in most of cases but if you're updating `LiveData` on response of that call then it's good to make it separately like during init block.
2. It's good practice not to allow Ui *(Activity/Fragments)* to modify `LiveData`s of `ViewModel` directly. So, that's good sign you're following such pattern by having private `MutableLiveData` exposed as public `LiveData`, but do it correctly as suggested.
3. Side note: Your view model doesn't need to be `LifecycleObserver`. `LifecycleObserver` is used for some custom class/component which needs to be managed by their self by silently observing/depending on activity lifecycle independently. That's not the use case of `ViewModel`.

---

The only thing that I found why your code wasn't working correctly is because you were creating & observing `ViewModel` & `LiveData` over & over again as new objects from `onResume` method where you called `hello()` method.

Let me know if something don't make sense or missing.

Comment: have you seen the problem? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352752/user-login-using-viewmodel-and-retrofit/64382762#64382762

Comment: @apj123 Yes, I looked into question and seems like the solution provided  by epicpandaforce is correct. All you're missing is few dependencies from gradle according to that code. I.e. ViewModel-ktx etc.

Comment: hey need help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531897/clicklistener-not-working-in-recyclerview